# adding model validation errors in rescue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have the following model with a virtual attribute

```
class Mytimeperiod < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates presence of :from_dt
  validates_format_of :from_dt, :with => /\A\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4}\Z/, :message => "format is mm/dd/yyyy"

  def from_dt
     self.from_date.strftime("%m/%d/%Y") if !self.from_date.blank?
  end

  def from_dt=(from_dt)
    self.from_date = Date.parse(from_dt)
  rescue
    self.errors.add_to_base("invalid from dt")
  end
end
```

I am using `<%= f.error_messages %>` to display the error messages on the form.

I am using from_dt as a virtual attribute (string). The 'presence of' and 'format of' validation errors show up on the form, but when the user enters an invalid date format on the form and Date.Parse raises an exception I have a 'errors.add_to_base' statement in the rescue clause. Can anyone tell me why this error does not show up in the form error messages when I disable the 'format of' validation.

thanks.

Answer (score 12):

Errors added outside of the validation callbacks will be removed when validation gets run -
[ActiveModel](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/75b985e4e8b3319a4640a8d566d2f3eedce7918e/activemodel/lib/active_model/validations.rb#L178)

So you have to add your errors from within a validation callback, not in a setter.  This should work:

```
class Mytimeperiod < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates presence of :from_dt
  validates_format_of :from_dt, :with => /\A\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4}\Z/, :message => "format is mm/dd/yyyy"

  validate :from_dt_must_parse

  def from_dt
     self.from_date.strftime("%m/%d/%Y") if !self.from_date.blank?
  end

  def from_dt=(from_dt)
    self.from_date = Date.parse(from_dt)
  rescue
    @from_dt_parse_error = "not recognizable as a date"
  end

  def from_dt_must_parse
    self.errors[:from_dt] = @from_dt_parse_error
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax looks OK. If you're having issues testing in the console, make sure to do `reload!` (or exit and run `script/console` again).

If the only reason you're using a virtual attribute is to validate the date format, don't forget you can make your own validations with the `validate` method (untested):

```
class Mytimeperiod < ActiveRecord::Base

  protected

  def validate
    date = Date.parse(from_date)
  rescue
    errors.add("from_date", "date is invalid")
  end
end
```

This has the advantage of adding errors to the field rather than the object.

Comment: issue is not with console. the error message is not displayed on the form

Comment: Did you try testing it in the console, or with a unit test? Are the errors added to the object?

Comment: I checked in console and the only error it shows is 'from_dt cannot be blank' which is because of the 'validates_presence_of' method in my class definiton. The error messages from the rescue clause are not added to the errors array. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

I believe the problem is actually just your syntax, you need to start add a `begin` to the start of the block that has the `rescue`:

```
def from_dt=(from_dt)
  begin
    self.from_date = Date.parse(from_dt)
  rescue
    self.errors.add_to_base("invalid from dt")
  end
end
```

Comment: There is no need for the begin block as method `def` is considered as the `begin` for the block. You can test this out in `irb`.